# error_404 on style.css load

Tags: javascript, java, css

I'm getting 404 error on style.css file load: GET http://localhost:8080/style.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404

Class path is correct for style.css file and I can open it from file. I'm using gradle and guice.

Reference to my style.css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
```

Project structure:

```
src
 - main
      - java
      - resources
          - META-INF
              - persistence.xml
      - web
          - css
              -- style.css
          - jsp
          - WEB-INF
              - shiro.ini
              - web.xml
          login.html
```

It's my first web-app and I'm confused having both resource and web folder, in sense that resource folder by default should contain static files and if I add stylesheet there I cannot access it through the link:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
```

I think problem is in my project configuration.
I'm using Ultimate intellij IDE and my project include web module.
Web Resource directory (in module and facets) points on my web folder, in Facets I have two source roots checked which points on main\java and main\resources folders and there is no web folder included.

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXkSg.png)

[Error in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYbv2.png)

Comment: The path in the error message doesn't contain the `css/` folder?

Comment: Oh, sorry, my mistake, I just relocated style.css file out of css folder to one line with html files, but this has the same result as you can see

Comment: Try clicking this: http://localhost:8080/style.css Now try this:  http://localhost:8080/css/style.css what is the result?

Comment: This localhost page can’t be found for both

Comment: Chris G.
I updated my question and added screenshot with error

Comment: This is a jsp project, right? Which means all requests are handled by Java server code, and there should be a point where requesting static files is addressed, as opposed to routes. Because as far as I can tell, when the server receives a request for `/css/style.css` or `/style.css`, it is not properly set up to send back the appropriate file.